# Easiest way to display childNodes NodeList? (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, nodes

I'm attempting to navigate the DOM tree and retrieve html comments and display them in alert box. This is as far as I can get, my alert box keeps returning empty. How do I properly display a nodeList array? I've searched for hours and cant seem to find any info that makes sense.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hidden Comments</title>
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Hidden Comments</h1>
    <script>
        function concatComs(){
            var c=document.getElementById('body');
            var array=[];
            for(var i=0;c.childNodes.length<i;i++){
                if(c.childNodes[i].nodeType==8) array[i]=c[i];   
            }
            alert(array.toString());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body" style="text-align: center">
    <!--you-->
    <h2>Find the hidden comments!</h2>
    <p>Look closely and you'll find them!</p><!--found-->
    <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="concatComs()"/> 
    <!--them-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop should start like:

```
for(var i=0; i < c.childNodes.length; i++){
```

Additionally, you probably want to add `c.childNodes[i]` to your `array`.

```js
function concatComs(){
    var c = document.getElementById('body');
    var array=[];
    for(var i=0; i < c.childNodes.length; i++){
        if(c.childNodes[i].nodeType==8) {
            array.push(c.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    var result = "";
    for(i in array) {
        result += array[i].textContent + " ";
    }
    document.write(result);
}
```

```html
<div id="body" style="text-align: center">
    <!--you-->
    <h2>Find the hidden comments!</h2>
    <p>Look closely and you'll find them!</p><!--found-->
    <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="concatComs()"/> 
    <!--them-->
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! But now when I press go I get: ,[object Comment],,,,,[object Comment],,,,[object Comment]. How do I get the actual comments themselves concatenated?

Comment: `data`, `nodeValue`, and `textContent` all seem to show the text in the comment.

Comment: this is brilliant, thank you. I've been struggling with this for hours. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can select comment strings with a regex expression like this

```
match(/<!--.*?-->/g)
```

then you can trim the first 4 and last 3 letter for each string

```
substr(4,comments[i].length-7)
```

Final result is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hidden Comments</title>    
    <script>
        function concatComs(){            
            var comments = document.body.innerHTML.match(/<!--.*?-->/g);

            for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) 
                comments[i] = comments[i].substr(4,comments[i].length-7);

            alert(comments);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body" style="text-align: center">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Hidden Comments</h1>
    <!--you-->
    <h2>Find the hidden comments!</h2>
    <p>Look closely and you'll find them!</p><!--found-->
    <input type="button" value="Go!" onClick="concatComs()"/> 
    <!--them-->
</body>

</html>
```

btw you should place your h1 tag inside the body not head.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would use this code, if I didn't HAVE to use nodeType in some way. Part of the project is to use childNodes and get familiar with the idea of nodes so this would defeat the purpose. Any ideas on how to do it like that?